# Excel: Averaging Columns and Auto Populating Sub Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Im very new to Microsoft Excel (2016).

I have a data set where I want to average all of the data points from one column for a certain location. Example:

```
**Days Open**   **Site**
Not Closed  
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
1           Boulder, USA
1           Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Eden Prairie, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
4           Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
1           Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Eden Prairie, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
7           Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Cluj, Romania
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Nanjing, China
8          Boulder, USA
4          Boulder, USA
9          Nanjing, China
6          Boulder, USA
1          Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
Not Closed  Boulder, USA
2          Nanjing, China
```

I want to completely disregard the "Not Closed" Data points.

My end goal would be to display say..

```
Boulder, 21
Nanjing, 18 ... etc
```

Each "Site" with all of their "Days open" Averaged.

Thank you!

Comment: Explore and use 'Pivot Table' feature in Excel. All you need to do is replace default 'Count' option with 'Average' option in Values column of Pivot Table

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `AVERAGEIF`. (In this case we'll put it in column E)

In your case, assuming you are using columns A and B , you could write:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B$2:B$100,D1,A$2:A$100)
```

where cell `D1` contains the value you want to sum e.g. Boulder.